# Text 'null' could not be parsed at index 0 error

Tags: android

i used threeten and Google Play console says my code only occurs in Samsung s9 and s20.
here is my error and my code

**Error Message**

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'null' could not be parsed at index 0

FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
Process: com.playhead.timbre, PID: 20573
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'null' could not be parsed at index 0
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseToBuilder(DateTimeFormatter.java:1588)
    at org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1491)
    at org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:444)
    at com.playhead.timbre.Function.localTime(Function.java:581)
    at com.playhead.timbre.Feed.Feed_Main.TimeOutRefresh(Feed_Main.java:229)
    at com.playhead.timbre.Feed.Feed_Frame.onHiddenChanged(Feed_Frame.java:91)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:374)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

**My Code [Function.Class]**

```
    public static boolean localTime(String timeout){ //timeout = "2022-02-20 18:20:36"

            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime serverDate = LocalDateTime.parse(timeout, formatter);  //<< Function.java:581
            org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime localDate = org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.now();

            Log.e("LocalTime", "server:" + serverDate + " local:" + localDate);

            return localDate.isAfter(serverDate);

    }
```

Comment: String `timeout` is probably coming into this call as `"null"` (as a string value containing text `"null"`), you can either check that `timeout` does not contain text `"null"` in this method or you can show us the code at the call site (the code that calls this `localTime(timeout)`) and you update the code there, to not allow `timeout` containing text `"null"` through.

Comment: @Ma3x   string 'null' ?? I'm initializing and using timeout as follows. string timoeut ="";  And should I use if(timeout.qual("null") to exclude it? Is not if(timeout == null)?

Comment: Yes, the timeout string contains just "null" (a string of length 4). You get this exception when you pass a string containing the text `"null"` into `LocalDateTime.parse`. This is likely a bug at the call site, so you should show us the code where your `localDate(timeout)` method is called. If you would be passing in a `null` value (not string of length 4 "null", but an actual null value), then the exception would be `java.lang.NullPointerException: text must not be null`.

Comment: @Ma3x thanks bro I'll give it a try. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the exception `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'null' could not be parsed at index 0` when you pass a string of length 4 containing "null" into the `LocalDateTime.parse` method.

If you would be passing an actual value of `null`, the exception would have been `java.lang.NullPointerException: text must not be null`.

I checked both cases in actual code by calling `org.threeten.bp.format.LocalDateTime.parse(text, formatter)`.

At the call site(s) you should make a `try/catch` block to handle all invalid timestamps, or you could do checks to avoid passing invalid timestamps to the parse method.

If you decide to go with the `try/catch` approach, your code at call site(s) should be updated to something like this

```
try {
  String timeout = ... // your current code getting the timeout
  boolean isAfterServerDate = localTime(timeout)
  // ... other code
}
catch(Exception e) {
  // parsing of the timeout failed for some reason
  // e.getMessage contains the reason
}
// ... other code
```

If you decide to go without `try/catch` then you have to check for all invalid timestamp cases. Text containing `"null"` is one such case, but maybe you will have an empty string (`""`) sometimes as well? What about an actual `null` value, can that happen in your code? I suggest the `try/catch` approach.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Why do you think the error only occurs in s9 and s20? Not all samsung phone, only s9, s20 

Comment: @Nullfi Depends how exactly you are obtaining the timeout value. You did not share that part of the code, so it is hard to tell. Do you see many other devices (also non Samsung devices) where this Exception has never happened? How exactly do you obtain the timeout string?

Comment: 1. The device with an exception was output as an error in the Google play console. Other than the two devices(s9, s20), I can't see any other devices. 2.timeout is the String value sent by the server. like "2022-02-21 09:49"